# Tela login C# com banco de dados firebird com erro

Tags: c#, firebird

Pessoal estou fazendo um projeto e com banco de dados firebird mas, na hora de autenticar o usuário, está retornando verdadeiro mesmo se não existir usuário cadastrado no banco com a linha `if (ER.HasRows)`, e por isso não está caindo no `else`. Não estou achando o erro no código.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

```
FbConnection CON = new FbConnection();
CON.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.bdHTSisFinanceiro;
FbCommand CM = new FbCommand();
CM.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
try
{
    CM.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TBUSUARIO WHERE LOGIN_USU = @LOGINUSU AND SENHA_USU = @SENHAUSU";
    CM.Connection = CON;
    CM.Parameters.Clear();
    CM.Parameters.Add("LOGINUSU", FbDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario.Login;
    CM.Parameters.Add("SENHAUSU", FbDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario.Senha;
    FbDataReader ER;
    CON.Open();
    ER = CM.ExecuteReader();

    if (ER.HasRows)
    {
        while (ER.Read())
        {
            usuario.Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(ER["COD_USU"]);
            usuario.DataCadastro = Convert.ToDateTime(ER["DATACAD_USU"]);
            usuario.Status = Convert.ToChar(ER["STATUS_USU"]);
            usuario.Nome = Convert.ToString(ER["NOME_USU"]);
            usuario.Login = Convert.ToString(ER["LOGIN_USU"]);
            usuario.Senha = Convert.ToString(ER["SENHA_USU"]);
            usuario.CpfCnpj = Convert.ToString(ER["CPF_USU"]);
            usuario.Nivel = Convert.ToChar(ER["NIVEL_USU"]);
            usuario.Email = Convert.ToString(ER["EMAIL_USU"]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        usuario.Login = null;
        usuario.Senha = null;
    }
    return usuario;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
   CON.Close();
}
```

Por exemplo, tenho um usuário Master, senha 123. Se eu digitar mat senha 1, ele retorna verdadeiro e entra no sistema. Só tenho este usuário cadastrado Master. Coloquei o breakpoint, ele entra no `if` e não executa `while (ER.Read())`. Tá estranho: ele não deveria entrar no `if`. Eu nunca usei o firebird. Acho que fiz algo errado.

Comment: Se você retirar o HasRows e deixar apenas o while. Experimente e veja o que dá. Se estiver no while faz aquilo, senão, é porque não há nada para ler e aí faz o que você colocou no else do hasrows.

Comment: Você estava em Debug? Se você executou o `Read` enquanto inspecionava, o reader passa para a próxima linha e não executa. Tenta rodar sem debug e vê se dá o mesmo resultado. Dá uma lida nessas questões: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464012/asp-net-datareader-values e  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493955/datareader-has-rows-and-data-trying-to-read-from-it-says-no-data-is-present

Comment: após `ER = CM.ExecuteReader();` mostre uma mensagem `MessageBox.Show(CM)` se houver necessidade add `ToString()` e verifique se a `query` esta rodando corretamente.